# Does it make sense to have several subnets under a ethernet port for a dhcp configuration?

Tags: subnet, dhcp-server

I would like to know if it makes sense to set several subnets under a ethernet port. The configuration on dhcpd.conf is listed below:

```
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    #ethernet port enp5s0;
    range 192.168.10.100 192.168.10.120;
    range 192.168.10.200 192.168.10.220;
    option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2;
    option routers  192.168.10.1;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 259200;
}
subnet 192.168.30.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    #ethernet port enp5s0;
    range 192.168.30.100 192.168.30.120;
    range 192.168.30.200 192.168.30.220;
    option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2;
    option routers  192.168.30.1;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 259200;
}
subnet 192.168.40.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    #ethernet port enp7s0;
    range 192.168.40.100 192.168.40.120;
    range 192.168.40.200 192.168.40.220;
    option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2;
    option routers  192.168.40.1;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 259200;
}
```

Comment: Does it make sense... in what sense? For what purpose?

Comment: Actually that is my point. As far as I know, it makes no sense but maybe there are some cases which are beyond my imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Does it makes sense to set several subnets under a ethernet port? No. Having different ip address ranges on a network is typically done to seperate networks and control access via a router or it's just a logistical thing where the router will handle getting traffic from one to the other.

Comment: in your case, it is absolutely sensible that a dhcp server provides a unique subnet through one of its ethernet ports on it, am I right?